# Differential equation (Clairaut)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

**Problem**: I have to solve the following differential equation (which is supposed to be Clairaut's):
$$y=x(y')^2-\frac{1}{y'},$$
where $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}.$

**What I have tried**: Because it says that is Clairaut's, I proceed by differentiating with respect to $x$. With an ideal CLairaut's differential equation, you could "*isolate*" every term that is multiplied by $\frac{d^2y}{dx}$ and, on the other side of the equality, you will get a zero. From there, it easy and you end up getting a family of curves [Link: [Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation). The problem is the square in $x(y')^2,$ that messes up everything and I cannot isolate the terms in the right way.

I also tried using Mathematica

```
DSolve[{y[x] == x (y[x]')^2 - 1/(y[x]')}, y[x], x],
```

but it gives an error

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -(1/y').
```

I tried Python with Sympy, but failed too.

I tried a variable change, but I do not manage to find the optimal to *simplify* the equation and solve it following the regular procedure.

Comment: the Clairaut DE is of the form $y=xy'+...$

Comment: This is a [d'Alembert's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_equation).

Comment: Try to solve it as 
    DSolve[y[x] y'[x] - x y'[x]^3 - 1 == 0, y, x]  Mathematica gives a long answer.

Comment: I couldn't solve it analytically, try to solve it with softwares. has it any initial condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [d'Alembert's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_equation).  Letting $p=y'$, we have
$$
y=xp^2-\frac1p
$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$,
$$
p=p^2+2xp\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac1{p^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
So
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}p}=\frac{2}{1-p}x+\frac1{p^3-p^4}
$$
which integrates to $x = \frac{c}{(p-1)^2} - \frac1{2 (p - 1)^2 p^2} + \frac1{(p - 1)^2 p}$ and thus
$$
y=xp^2-\frac1p=\dots
$$

Comment: How do you integrate and get the $x=...$, because the first term on the right depends on $x$ and $p$.

Comment: You have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}p}+\frac{2}{p-1}x=\frac1{p^3-p^4}$ i.e., $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}p}((p-1)^2 x)=\frac{1-p}{p^3}$, etc.